# How to stop sound in pygame?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

Ok so basically I'm working on this pygame game and I'm using the mixer sub module for sounds. However, in pygame if you want to stop a sound, the sound must finish its cycle until it can be stopped. For all my sounds this is ok as they can be a looped 1 second sound. However, I use a falling sound which needs to constantly play in a cycle, but cycling a falling sound that is only 1 second long doesn't sound very effective. So, ultimately I want to know if there is a way to stop a 7 second sound loop instantly without it finishing a cycle.

Comment: @notcompletelyrational doesn't that just pause all sounds?

Comment: yeah it does. I think that was irrelevant and i answered before really thinking. deleted it now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the pygame documentation for pygame.mixer

```
pygame.mixer.pause()
```

will temporarily stop playback of **all** sound channels. You can start them all playing again with;

```
pygame.mixer.unpause()
```

For an individual sound, whilst it will stop after a full cycle, you can immediately affect it's volume with;

```
pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume(0)
```

So what I'd try first is stopping the sound at the same time as setting it's volume to zero and seeing if that solves your problem. Alternatively, you can split your mixer into Channels for better controlling sound playback, which will give you the ability to use

```
pygame.mixer.Channel.pause()
pygame.mixer.Channel.unpause()
```

On specific groups of sounds rather than all sound. You create a mixer channel with;

```
pygame.mixer.Channel(id)
```

You can then play specific sounds on that channel with;

```
pygame.mixer.Channel.play(Sound, loops=0, maxtime=0, fade_ms=0)
```

This would also allow you to more dynamically adjust the levels of various types of sounds in your game - for example, environment, music, weather, voices and how they overlap each other, just keep in mind a channel can only play one sound at a time. Because of this, it may by prudent to use;

```
free_channel = pygame.mixer.find_channel()
free_channel.play(Sound)
```

or more simply;

```
pygame.mixer.find_channel().play(Sound)
```

For everything except your 'falling' channel.

Comment: I used that method and it works except my sound has been cut down to a second long?

Comment: Hey Dan, which method exactly did you use? 

If you went via playing sounds via channels - you'll need to make sure you didn't accidentally cut-off one playing sound with another - a channel can only playback a single Sound at time.

Comment: Yeah I created a channel for the falling sound and the other sounds are just mixer sounds, there is no channel used with them.When the falling sound is being played no over sounds are being played until the falling sound has been paused. Do I need to use a channel for the other sounds?

Comment: My understanding was that if you don't specify a channel for a sound, it creates one just for it. But what you might want to do is use 'pygame.mixer.find_channel()' to return a non-busy channel and always play new sounds on a channel that returns.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out what the problem is. Basically for some reason when I used the sound without the channel within the game loop it would play once but not stop until it finished. However with the channel now the sound is playing from the beginning constantly at 60 fps. This means if I take it out of the game loop it works, but the program cant check if the condition has been met for the sound so it plays when a new game starts. Is there a way for pygame to play it once at the correct condition and wait the correct amount before playing it again?

Comment: If you're trying to loop the sound indefinitely (until you pause it) you can use  play(loops=-1). What you can also do is check if the sound is already playing in your channel with Channel.get_busy() - which returns a True/False, and only begin playing it again if it's not currently playing. Does that help at all?

Comment: I used Channel.get_busy but it runs the sound at the correct time it just constantly runs it again and again, so I guess I could see if it is true and if so, the sound needs to wait a correct amount of time before playing another. Is there a way to play one sound wait and play another? Also I get what you mean with the loops=-1 but I still need to check if the condition is met which needs to be within the game loop, so the issue is still there. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: No problem! I'm interested in the solution myself now. So... Is there a way to play one sound, wait then play another - if you want it to play directly afterwards, then yes! You can use pygame.mixer.Channel.queue(Sound) to queue it!